# display roles checkboxes in custom register page in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7, drupal-theming

i have created my own custom register page in drupal 7 but i can not display roles checkboxes

my code is:

```
<div class="register-name-field"><?php echo drupal_render($form['account']['roles']); ?></div>
```

but role did not appear??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This portion appears for users who have the `Administer permissions` permission.

I don't think it is safe to allow anonymous users to choose the role they belong to.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it by custom code you can use [Auto Assign Role](http://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole) module to show checkboxes on registration page to allow user to select its own role.

To enable role field in registration page install and enable [Auto Assign Role](http://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole) module and navigate to 'admin/config/people/autoassignrole/user' page. Enable 'User role assignment' option, select roles you want to show on registration page and there are other option as well to customize this field.

This will show role field in user registration page.